# How to keep inactive timestamped items in agenda

Tags: org-agenda, timestamped

To view inactive stamps in my agenda, I press `v` and `[`. This displays the inactive stamps for the specific day I am in in the `org-agenda`. However, if I press `B` of `F` to move back or forward one day, the effect of `[` is no longer valid and I must press `[` again to keep seeing those inactive items. Is it possible to keep inactive items showing in agenda when browsing days? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```el
(setq org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps t)
```

in your init file (untested).

Its doc string (`C-h v org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps`) says:

> org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps is a variable defined in ‘org-agenda.el’.
>
> Its value is nil
>
> Non-nil means include inactive time stamps in agenda.
> Dynamically scoped.

The fact that it is dynamically scoped and is not customizable indicates that it is meant to be set using `v [` interactively in the agenda, but setting its value to `t` should enable it permanently. Note however that `v [` will be a no-op in that case.

Comment: Thanks for this! However, this does not include archived inactive stamps, right? My archived files are not agenda files because it would take too long to load them.